# Linq query to select top 20 items of a list with a length restriction on its property

Tags: c#, linq

```
  public IList<TagWithCount> GetTagList()
        {
        var query=(from c in this.Query() where c.coupons.Where(d => d.isPublish == true).Count() > 2 select new TagWithCount { tag = c, count = c.coupons.Count }).ToList().OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid()).Skip(0).Take(75).ToList();
        return query;
    }
```

THis is the method which i am calling ..

```
  var a = context.tagService.GetTagList().Distinct(c => c.tag.name.Trim()).ToList() ;
return View(a.Take(20));
```

I want to return 20 tags but not greater than 20 words or less then 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is what you want.. not too sure though.. your question is vague..

```
context.tagService.GetTagList().Where(x => x.tag.name.Length < 20 
                                   && x.tag.name.Length>4)
                               .Take(20).ToList();
```